# Grails warm up time after upgrade to 3

Tags: grails3

After upgrading a grails application (usage of multiple inline plugins, > 130 controllers, > 140 services, > 180 domain classes, > 600 GSPs) from 2.5.4 to 3.2.8:

- `grails run-app` before update: 2:10 minutes.
- `grails run-app` after update: 5:50 minutes.

Most of the time the grails 3.2.8 run-app is hanging at ":boot-run". Especially after spring security core has initialized (about 2 minutes after start) it hangs for about 4 minutes. Additionally the CPU usage is very low compared to grails 2.5.4.

The test was repeated with different machines and faced similar results (Mac, Linux and Windows machines).

What can be the reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Should you not ask this question on grails-core forums ?

Comment: Also, I just remember seeing this few days ago. You might want to look at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/640

Comment: I saw this, but its related to runtime performance, that is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

That's incredible: If you restart intellij before running ´grails run-app´ for the very first time, the boot time is 2 minutes with grails 3.

Do not use the restart button in intellij 2017.1.1.

Update

1. There is definitely some memory leaks in runtime environment of IntelliJ.
2. Updating to Java 8 SDK improved situations a lot.
3. Adding "bootRun { jvmArgs = ["-Xmx4096m"] }" to build.gradle was key succes.

App starts now in 30 seconds. I would recommend to upgrade to grails 3.